# Passing and updating variables between classes in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a reusable higher solution for instant/client side form validations in react.

I thought of creating a validation class with validation methods and simply passing the relevant ones to the form fields.

So for example if I have a required email field it will be passed two methods from the validation class to check that.

Here's an abbreviated example:

```
class Validate {
  constructor (value) {
    this.value = value
  }

  required = () => {
    console.log('in validator required, value is :', this.value)
    if (!this.value.toString().trim().length) {
      return 'required'
    }
  }
  lt = () => {
    if (this.value.toString().trim().length < 50) {
      return 'extra details must be at least 50 characters'
    }
  }
}

export default class Form extends Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.validate = new Validate(this.state.email) // Passing the field to the instance here means it will be undefined even after the state changed with new value for email.
  }
  /* ... */

  render () {
    const {
      email
    } = this.state.value
    const {
      required
    } = this.validate
    return (
      <form className='form__wrapper' onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <InputText
          type='text'
          value={email}
          validations={required}
          /* ... */
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

const InputText = ({ value, validate }) => (
  <div className={`field-wrapper ${customClass}`} >
    <input
      value={value}
      /* ... */
    />
    {value ? validate(value) : null}
  </div>
)
```

My problem as, you can see from the comment above, is that I don't know how to pass my variables to the class so they will get updated when the user input data and the value of the email field has changed.

Comment: It seems a problem related to `this`. When `validate` is called, it will not be called with the appropriate `this`. Try replacing  `const {
      required
    } = this.validate` with `const required = this.validate.required.bind(this.validate)`

Comment: Is it just trying to validate once, and then not updating the validations?

Comment: That's not the issue if I change  this.validate = new Validate('some text') it's not undefined in the method. But if I use the variable from the state the Validate class is instantiated with an undefined value for the email, because the email is indeed undefined at that moment, but later when the user inputs an email the Validate class still has undefined as the value for the email field.

Comment: @Dream_Cap No I'm trying to update the validations as well in real time

Comment: Have you thought about having a handleChange function that sits on the form component and then calls to the validate class on every change to the input for validation? I'm not sure if it'll work, but maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truthfully, what I feel javascript is meant to be a functional language rather than a OOP one.

However, this feels like an anti-pattern to me. The value has to be updated within the class it belongs to even in OOPs (well other than public variables, but even then they are directly changed rather than by reference as far as I remember.

So the two solutions that I would recommend are:

1. The easiest, use functional programming, pass in the values directly to the function.
2. Make Validate function wrap around the form component, and then pass in email as a prop to form component, and change events too should be passed down and the ntriggered in form component.